# Insert specific values into mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, insert

I have the following problem:
I would't insert all the values in my db.
So, i would insert only id,tessera,nome,sex. I thought i had to write something like this:

```
INSERT INTO  registries(id,tessera,'',nome,sex) VALUES (35983,35983,'DOG', 'FABIO', 'M')
```

I don't want to insert the DOG value in my db cause I don't have any attribute in my schema to save it.
I have 3000 rows and I take this row as example so I can't simply delete the DOG value and the attribute field in my sql query. 
I remember that I have to use something like this

```
INSERT INTO  registries(id,tessera,'',nome,sex)
```

I mean, I have to write `''` to not consider the value in that position.
but MySQL gives me an error..

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this situation in following ways.

1. create temporary table on same server. Insert all data in temporary table then use insert into select statement and select required fields.
2. create temporary column and insert data in that column and delete temporary column

   ```
   INSERT INTO registries (id,tessera,new_column,nome,sex) 
   VALUES (35983, 35983, '', 'FABIO', 'M');
   ```

Now

```
DROP COLUMN new_column from registries;
```

Comment: is it  not possible to use something similar to the syntax that i wrote in the first post?

Comment: INSERT syntax only takes columns available in table
We can use any constant value in SELECT statement LIKE SELECT id,tessera,'MY Value',nome,sex FROM registeries WHERE id=35983  will result in  35983, 35983, MY Value, FABIO, M

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming dog is a column name):

```
INSERT INTO  registries (id,tessera,dog_name,nome,sex) VALUES (35983, 35983, '', 'FABIO', 'M')
```

If dog_name is allowed to be NULL (which it is by default) you could also just not insert any value, like this:

```
INSERT INTO  registries (id,tessera,nome,sex) VALUES (35983, 35983, 'FABIO', 'M')
```

Comment: no, dog is a value. I don't have the dog_name in the attributes of my db, so i don't want to insert it

Comment: see my edit, this will insert and empty string as dog_name

Comment: so, i badly explained my problem. I can't edit every single row , deleting the value of the dog_name. So i want to don't consider the attribut dog_name

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your exact question in that case. Do you want to add a column?

Comment: no problem. I think i have to use the Narendra Yadav's solution. Thank you :)